# Is it possible to create an org-link to a custom agenda view?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-link

I'd like to add links to custom agenda commands within org files and other agenda views.

I think the answer would likely use `org-add-link-type`.

I also know that you can call a custom agenda view with the following code:

`(org-agenda nil "p")`

But I don't know how to combine the two, or if it is even possible.

Ideally, I would like be able to create a heading that launches a custom agenda. Something like the following:

`* [[Code which I don't know][View current project tasks by assignment]]`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define a new link type: you can have `elisp` links that execute an arbitrary Lisp form - because the code is arbitrary, they can be dangerous so you get a question whether you are OK with following the link. See [External Links](https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html) in the manual. For example:

```org
* [[elisp:(org-agenda nil "p")][View current project tasks by assignment]]
```

N.B. No space between the colon and the opening paren!